# Can I use Clojure's derive to create a hierarchy of my defrecord class types?

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I would like to do something like:

```
(defrecord Base [])
(defrecord Person [])
(defrecord Animal [])

(derive Person Base)
(derive Animal Base)

(isa? Animal Person)
```

Is this possible?

### Update:

I've since realized that this is not possible so I am doing something like this:

```
(defmulti type class)
(defmethod type Base [_] ::base )
(defmethod type Animal [_] ::animal )
(defmethod type Person [_] ::person )
```

Does this make sense or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Records are Java classes.  As the [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) page states:

> You can also use a class as the child
>   (but not the parent, the only way to
>   make something the child of a class is
>   via Java inheritance).

You can't extend classes with records but you can [implement interfaces](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/11/23/implementing-java-interfaces-with-clojure-records/).  Using interfaces to play in the Java class hierarchy, you might be able to make something work.